# How to add datePicker by class dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using "jquery-1.9.1.js" and my javascript code is as below:

```
$('.fromSearch').on('focus', function(){
var $this = $(this);
  if(!$this.data('datepicker')) {
   $this.removeClass("hasDatepicker");
   $this.datepicker();
   $this.datepicker("show");
  } 
});
```

my html code is this:

```
<div id="duration" class="duration">
    <td><input type="text" id="fromSearch" class="fromSearch"></td>
</div>
```

PROBLEM:
I am generating "fromSearch" (date picker) dynamically, lets say 5 date pickers, but I get date picker only for the first time!

I have been working on solutions provided on similar questions, but none of them is working for me. Can any body help me figuring out where I am going wrong?
Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: can you provide a demo fiddle so it will be easier to understand?

Comment: I would say you need to delegate event, e.g: `$(document).on('focus', '.fromSearch',  function(){...});` That's said, beware, IDs must be unique on document context. And BTW, your HTML markup is invalid

Comment: You need to use a delegated event handler as the `.fromSearch` element is added after the DOM has been loaded.

Comment: @A. Wolff, yes ids are unique for each of the dynamically generated text box. It goes like this fromSearch, fromSearch2, fromSearch3 ... fromSearch5 for each of the date pickers

Comment: @Amir Still be aware a TD cannot be direct descendant of DIV element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try as below:

```
$('body').on('focus', '.fromSearch', function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

**UPDATE**

To pass date to a function write `onselect` event in your `datepicker` as below:

```
$('body').on('focus', '.fromSearch', function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
          onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                   //do necessary actions
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :) Meanwhile you can mark it as answer if it helped.. :)

Comment: @Rao, now how can I send selected date to a javascript function?

Comment: @Amir.. Updated the answer. Check and let me know!!

Comment: Yessss it worked too, sorry I cannot double Tick here :D 
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Anytime!! Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work.  You need to ensure you are including jQuery-ui.  DatePicker does not come bundled with jQuery

http://code.jquery.com/ui/